# Difference Between Differentiation on Time vs Position

Tags: derivatives

I'm hoping somebody could help me understand the difference between the following:

$$∂_tc(x,t)$$
$$∂_xc(x,t)$$

My understanding is the the top derivative would be something like velocity but what would that make the bottom derivative?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $c$ modeling? The interpretation depends on what $c$ represents.

Comment: c is just the concentration of a molecule. So these describe the movement of the molecule as a function of position x and time t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$∂_tc(x,t)$ represents the rate of change in $c$ with respect to $t$ (temperature) at a fixed $x$ (position), whereas $∂_xc(x,t)$ represents the rate of change in n $c$ with respect to $x$ (position) at a fixed $t$ (time).

Here is an example:

Consider a thin metal pipe filled with an aqueous solution being heated at only one end. Let $C(x, \, y)$ denote the concentration of a reactive solute $x$ meters from the beginning of the pipe at time $t$.

Here, $∂_tC(x,t)$ represents the rate of change of concentration of the solute at a specific fixed position from the beginning of the pipe, at any time $t$.

On the other hand, $∂_xC(x,t)$ represents the rate of change of concentration of the  solute at a specific fixed time at any position $x$.

Does this help?

Comment: Sorry should have made that clearer. t is time and x is position. Could you give me an example that helps me understand what a change in time at a fixed position would be like? I can understand how velocity would be described by change in position over a fixed time. But what about the former?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer.

Comment: This is just what I'm looking for, but what about time not temperature?

Comment: I edited all my temperatures into "time" :)

Comment: Beautiful, this makes sense. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!